# AADSTS50011 The reply uri specified in the request isn't using a secure scheme. PHP based on REST

Tags: php, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use Azure Active Directory authentication on a router but the redirection URLs that are configured in Azure Portal do not accept the HTTP protocol, it must be the HTTPS protocol.

I followed the example of **PHP** based on **REST** and for tests on localhost it works fine, the problem is when I try to do it on a router, after signing in with a Microsoft account it shows me "AADSTS50011: The reply uri specified in the request isn't using a secure scheme.".
How can I configure the application in Azure Portal so that I can use HTTP?
, that is to say that my redirect URL is *http://IP ROUTER/INDEX.PHP*

Note: In the documentation I have read that it does not accept HTTP, but I have seen websites that use authentication and all the URLs they use are HTTP.